# Parabola - Converting Cartesian Coordinates to Polar Coordinates

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

Just a simple parabola, $ y = x^2 $ .
So, doing the maths: $r sin  \theta = r^2 (cos(\theta))^2$. 
Then, I have $ r  = \frac{sin(\theta)}{(cos(\theta))^2}$ .

I'm interested when $ \frac{3\pi}{4} < \theta < \pi$.

But when I plot in Desmos Calculator, https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ms3eghkkgz, the polar and the cartesian equations at the same time, the result is not the same… I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, can you explain me please?

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fvyxkckqyn use this. Desmos has polar co-ords in built too

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: I also do think that is fine, but if it is, why did the website showed diferente things?